# Sources for Teffilin (tefillin) being called a crown

Tags: tefilin

I am looking for early sources of associating tefilin with a crown.

It is mentioned throughout kabalah that Tefillin is connected with the sefirah of Keser and is itself a crown which is worn on the head.

The Beis Yosef mentions that we dont wear tefillin mussaf Rosh Chodesh since we say keser in mussaf and it would be conflicting with the keser of the tefillin.

Here may be some more info regarding the Beis Yosef saying no teffilin for mussaf - https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_HaRadbaz_Volume_4.1151.2?vhe=Teshuvot_HaRadbaz,_Warsaw_1882&lang=bi

(Please try to be very specific with any sources cited, the best is if you can attach a link.)

Comment: Why do you think there might be such comparisons?

Comment: It is mentioned throughout kabalah that Tefillin is connected with the sefirah of Keser and is itself a crown which is worn on the head. The Beis Yosef mentions that we dont wear tefillin mussaf Rosh Chodesh since we say keser in mussaf and it would be conflicting with the keser of the tefilli.

Comment: @Targum your question would be improved if you added that information into the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i added it to the question.

Comment: The bracha of "oter yisrael be'tifara" refers to tefillin

Answer (score 1):

In “Posach Eliyahu” (which is from Tikuni Zohar) it says ״כתר עליון דאיהו…קרקפתא דתפילין״ - “the ‘Supernal Crown’ which is…the ‘scull of Tefillin”

Also the Beis Yosef (Orach Chaim 25:2) brings down a practical implication of this, and says that he heard, that the reason why it is customary to remove our Tefillin before Mussaf on Rosh Chodesh, is in order not to be “crowned” in our Tefillin while reciting “Kesser” (which is to crown Hashem)